# Change the file from .mat to .txt

Tags: matlab

How can I convert a .mat file into a .txt file with all the headers? I do not know how many fields are present.

How do I export this data? I have [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).

I tried in MATLAB:

```
load('test_data.mat'); 
save('test_data.txt', '-ascii');
```

It did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MATLAB you can simply execute the command

```
load 'file.mat'
```

which will load all the variables in the .mat file into your workspace.  You can then do something like:

```
save('newfile.txt', 'var1, 'var2', ..., '-ascii')
```

to save the variables you specify into an ASCII file.  The `save()` function has a lot of arguments and options, check the documentation.

And if you are not using MATLAB your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: He mentioned he doesn't know how many fields are present, that means the variables are unknown.